# How to evaluate the diffrences between a rgb image and a binary one?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

All my ground truth images are color but my program is a genetic algorithm working with binary images. I do not know how to compute the fitness in order to see the similarity and differences between the ground truth and my binary image.[image: Ground_Truth_Example]

Answer (score 0):

The colors you see are most likely just classes, the colors solely exist to showcase the differences better. To compute the similarity, you can use the `Dice similarity coefficient` or the `F1 Score`. If you need a more granular overview, i suggest you compute so called `Confusion Matrices`.

Long story short: Each color represents a different class in your output, you can calculate the metrics mentioned above to compare your output to your groundtruth.